# How to run Junit tests at random number

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a test suite class `TestSuite` and `TestA` class

```java
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses({TestA.class})
    public class TestSuite {
    }
```

```java
    public class TestA {
    
        @Test
        public void test1(){
            System.out.println("test1");
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test2(){
            System.out.println("test2");
        }
    
        @Test
        public void test3(){
            System.out.println("test3");
        }
    }
```

How to randomly run just 2 tests of all 3? Searched and looks like I need to create a custom runner. Any example for this? Thanks!

Update:
Figured out we just need a custom runner for this

```
public class TestRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    private static final int MAX_TESTS_TO_RUN = 2;
    public TestRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
        List<FrameworkMethod> methods = super.computeTestMethods();

        List<FrameworkMethod> shuffledMethods = new ArrayList<>(methods);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledMethods);

        return new ArrayList<>(shuffledMethods.subList(0, Math.min(methods.size(), MAX_TESTS_TO_RUN)));
    }
}
```

Also, if your test class already has a runner with it then you need to create a rule and add rule to the individual test class

Comment: This is unlikely to be possible out of the box. Tests are all about determinism. But you can create one test and call 2 of 3 scenarios with assertions inside it in any way you choose include random.

Comment: Why do you want to call a random number of tests instead of running all of them?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Junit, this is not possible out of the box**. You would have to write a custom `org.junit.runner.Runner` implementation to achieve this.

However, I think what you are asking is [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You should ask yourself why doing something like this is necessary. Junit5 for instance provides tonnes of methods [to run tests conditionally](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-conditional-test-execution), depending on Java version, env variables, specific OS, etc. So you can decide wether to run tests either [statically](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0-M2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Disabled.html#:%7E:text=%40Disabled%20is%20used%20to%20signal,are%20automatically%20disabled%20as%20well.) or [dynamically](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.2.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/condition/DisabledOnOs.html) (depending on the runtime conditions) in Junit. Most likely that is what you want.

Answer (score -2):

you will need to make the objects static and then where it says import and have your test number run here replace it and call your objects.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        //this switch makes checks for a random number between 1 and 3
        switch((int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(3-1+1)+1)) {
            case 1:
                // import and have test 1 run here
                break;
            case 2:
                // import and have test 2 run here
                break;
            case 3:
                // import and have test 3 run here
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).